# QProcess and setpgid

Tags: c++, qt, posix, pid, qprocess

I've got a Qt GUI application that wraps a console process. I use QProcess to launch it and display its outputs in a QTextEdit. However, I do it in a special way (running a shell) because the process needs to have access to some environment variables which are exported in the .bashrc.
Also, to properly kill the console process when the QTextEdit window is closed, I set the pgid of the GUI process to the pid of the called console process.

It goes something like this :

```
process->start(getenv("SHELL"), QStringList() << "-i");
setpgid(process->pid(),0);
contentsWindow->setProcessPid(process->pid());

if (process->waitForStarted())
{
    connect(contentsWindow,SIGNAL(aboutToClose()),this,SLOT(terminateLaunch()));
    process->write("./yarprosbridge --from bridge_conf.ini --gui\n");
}
```

It works fine when I launch it from QtCreator or from Nautilus, but something goes wrong when I launch it from the Terminal. If I remove the `setpgid` instruction, it works fine. If not, the QTextEdit stays empty but I get no error whatsoever (even with `getpgid` which succeeds) and the state of the QProcess is fine.

What could cause this ? In what way can it be different if I launch it from QtCreator or from the Terminal ?

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the environment variables in both situations and comparing them?

Comment: Just did that. With QtCreator, I get very few environment variables, the ones I need are not listed (which is why I did the call to `getenv("SHELL")` in the first place). I also noticed it works fine when I launch it from Nautilus. From the terminal, I obviously get all the environment variables including the ones I need (since the .bashrc was loaded before the gui process even started).

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that I'm changing the pgid of the launching terminal which somehow creates an undefined behaviour ?

Comment: I don't know, can't you test it to find out if makes a difference?

Comment: How can I test that out ? Nothing returns error codes, everything seems to be working fine, except that it doesn't from a Terminal...

Comment: Sorry, I meant test if there's a difference in the environment if you choose to set the group id, or not to set it.